# Why might my C# computation time be non-deterministic?

Tags: c#, .net

I am running a search algorithm which is fed at the start with a single seed. From this point on I expect the algorithm to behave in a deterministic fashion, which it largely does. I can largely verify this by looking at the 10,000th step, 20,000 step and seeing they are identical. What I am seeing different though is the length of thread processor time used to get to the same place (having taken identical paths). I am measuring the thread time with
ProcessThread.TotalProcessorTime.

To quantify this I have done some tests for you. I varied the run time and measured the number of solutions evaluated within this time

---

```
    30s         60s          120s        120s
473,962     948,800     1,890,668   1,961,532
477,287     954,335     1,888,955   1,936,974
473,441     953,049     1,895,727   1,960,875
475,606     953,576     1,905,271   1,941,511
473,283     951,390     1,946,729   1,949,231
474,846     954,307     1,840,893   1,939,160
475,052     952,949     1,848,938   1,934,243
476,797     957,179     1,945,426   1,951,542

475,034     476,599       473,831     486,721
  1,478       2,426        23,922      11,108
```

I repeated the test 8 times for each. The bottom two rows show the Average solutions evaluated over a 30 second period followed by the Standard Deviation. I repeated the 120s test as the standard deviation was so high the first time and much lower the second time.

If my algorithm is doing the same work then what could cause the same work to take different amounts of time? What random element is being introduced?

To clarify a few points:

1. I am talking about Thread Processor time and not Clock time
2. The algorithm runs on a single thread with no explicit interactions with other threads
3. This environment is Windows XP .Net C# Dual processor
4. It is a console application
5. The algorithm uses the processor and memory, only after it has finished will it print the result to screen.

Best Regards

Comment: Does you process have a dedicated processor?

Comment: I would guess you also aren't using a real-time OS, so hardware interrupts cause differences.

Comment: Are you evaluating your app, or the underlying system architecture?  I.e. how is this counter affected by thread switching, cache misses, process priority, etc.?

Comment: Also, remember Heisenberg's principle...

Comment: Your algorithm might be deterministic, however lots of other things are also happening on the machine at the same time that will have an effect (especialy so with a modern OS).  The only real way to make your total processor time deterministic would probably be to be the only thing running on the machine (i.e. no OS).

Comment: @Kragen even that wouldn't do it.

Comment: @Adam Actually I think it *probably* would - processors and memory are actually incredibly predictable and so excluding hardware failure or any sort of IO you should be able to predict this down to the processor cycle.

Comment: @Kragen I didn't spot the (no OS) part, there are less drastic ways to make it deterministic lol

Comment: @Howard : how big (absolute and relative) are those differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optimization, memory management (GC, allocation, paging, etc.) and Just in Time compilation.

Comment: And the CLR allocating memory.

Comment: Optimisation / JIT compilation are likely to be deterministic, i.e. the compiler will always compile the code up to look the same unless the settngs / compiler / code changes.

Comment: Well, GC is the most non-deterministic of all, and most likely to make a difference, but since it's *"a search algorithm"* with a possibly large search space, I would presume that paging will have a large effect.

Comment: @Adam: allocation is very fast and deterministic.

Comment: @Henk never said it wasn't, but it offers no guarantees about being able to respond in a given time - the OS will introduce problems here.  Deterministic systems need to offer these guarantees.

Answer (score 5):

On the processor level, cache misses and incorrect branch predicitions can both affect how much processor time might be taken from one run to another. On the framework level, JITing and GC can both affect it as well. The latter are more likely to be observed than the former.

Comment: Cache misses and incorrect branch predictions are likely to be deterministic as well, however there will also be OS-level aspects (such as memory allocations and when a thread gets preempted) that will also have an effect.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm might be deterministic, but absolutely none of the environment and runtime elements are:

- The code runs on a runtime that needs to allocate memory, non-deterministic from your point of view.
- The runtime has a garbage collector that runs at undetermined times for non-deterministic periods, from your point of view.
- The operating system is not soft or hard real time, so the processor management affects the timing.

All in all, don't expect deterministic behaviour in a non-deterministic system.  Windows CE supports hard real time, but you'd still need to use something other than .NET on it.

Bear in mind that "deterministic" is in a sense saying: "this piece of code takes *exactly* 20 milliseconds every single time it runs.  You have no hope of achieving this with a runtime that is non-deterministic on an OS that is non-deterministic.

Determinism in the sense of an operating system is usually less stringent than "exactly", more like: "I can guarantee that I reply within X, otherwise I will error".  Soft and hard real-time are more and less flexible on this point, respectively.

Comment: The GC point sounds OK, but the first and third bullet are false or at least debatable.

Comment: The third bullet isn't debatable, it is the scheduling engine in non-real time OS's that makes them non-real time in the first place.  The first point is really just to highlight that things inside the runtime are not offering up the contract that they guarantee to execute inside a certain time.  The CLR offers no guarantee that it will or will not trigger a GC, just that it *might*, and that it can guarantee you have enough memory to serve the request, just that you *might*.  Point being, don't expect real-time characteristics on non-real time systems...

Comment: Plus the OP was asking about things that cause the discrepancies, so my points are still valid.

Comment: Adam, it sounds like you're arguing about Elapsed Time, not ProcessorTime. All timeslot/scheduling influences should be filtered out, save maybe some small effects.

Comment: Yes, processor time will presumably remain constant assuming stuff like caching isn't a problem, but the elapsed time of the command remains unknown.  This is also important for real-time behaviour.

Comment: Adam, the question was about the time taken by an algorithm, not RT responses.

Comment: Henk, the question was about the time taken to run the algorithm... on .NET, presumably on a desktop, and what the random discrepancies in time could possibly be.  Expecting it to take the same amount of time every time opens the door for talking about real-time behaviour, and talking about that behaviour should lead to the conclusion that unless performed in such circumstances you cannot expect anything *other* than for each run to have slightly different timings.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Processor time is shared time, so any other activity happening on your machine can affect performance.</s>

I stand corrected.

Comment: Incorrect - Processor time is shared however the `ProcessThread.TotalProcessorTime` counter will only record time that the processor spends on that thread.  Any other activity happening on the machine won't be counted by this counter.

Comment: However, not entirely incorrect.  Physical processor time on one activity might remain constant, but time from start to end because a processor is changing tasks contributes to deterministic behaviour.

Comment: @Adam You mean due to context switching?

Comment: Not just that, the time slice given to the processor to perform a certain task, on a normal OS running more than one process the time-slice is non-deterministic from the perspective of the application.  It's easy to blow this into the realm of capable hardware, but the OP has stated .NET and not stated any hardware so I assume Windows Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

What resources is your algorithm uses? Are there any other process that use the same resources? This includes CPU, memory, IO (pagefile). Other processes will have an impact on the performance of your algorithm.

What is a difference in time? 1%? 10%?